# wiremock - Cannot resolve method 'willReturn' in 'Object'

Tags: java, wiremock

I'm trying examples of [stubbing](http://wiremock.org/docs/stubbing/) in my project, and having error: `Cannot resolve method 'willReturn' in 'Object'`

This is one of the examples:

```
@Test
public void exactUrlOnly() {
    stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/some/thing"))
            .willReturn(aResponse()
                .withHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain")
                .withBody("Hello world!")));
}
```

If I compile the project will have this error:

```
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method willReturn(com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.http.ResponseDefinition)
  location: class java.lang.Object
```

Anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Found the reason, Intellij autocompleted the import when I was typing `get`:

```
import static javax.swing.UIManager.get;
```

which should be

```
import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.get;
```